# Mitmproxy and installation with yocto recipes

Tags: python, yocto, mitmproxy

I want to install the third-party tool called [Mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) in an embedded Linux environment with a low footprint, e.g. a Raspberry PI.

Rather than install using a standard Raspbian OS, I want to customize the install with Yocto and define the packages.  This involves writing recipes to customize the packages that are installed.  A good example at a high leve is described [here](https://jumpnowtek.com/rpi/Raspberry-Pi-Systems-with-Yocto.html).

Unfortunately this involves appending various Python3 packages as well pip-mitmproxy as well as all the dependencies of pip-mitmproxy in the local.conf file, e.g.

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python3" 
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " pip-mitmproxy"
```

Different recipe files need to be added in this case.

The challenge that I've found is getting the right versions of all the dependencies.  I looked import pkg_resources but it doesn't seem to give me everything.   Is there another recommended approach perhaps by looking at the [source code.](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/tree/master/mitmproxy)

Comment: maybe install `mitmproxy` on normal Linux and use `pip freeze` to get list of installed modules with its version's numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created Python `venv` on normal Linux Mint so `pip freeze` shows me empty list

After installing `mitmproxy` I run again `pip freeze` and it shows me

```
blinker==1.4
Brotli==1.0.7
certifi==2020.6.20
cffi==1.14.1
click==7.1.2
cryptography==2.9.2
Flask==1.1.2
h11==0.9.0
h2==3.2.0
hpack==3.0.0
hyperframe==5.2.0
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
kaitaistruct==0.8
ldap3==2.7
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
mitmproxy==5.2
passlib==1.7.2
protobuf==3.11.3
publicsuffix2==2.20191221
pyasn1==0.4.8
pycparser==2.20
pyOpenSSL==19.1.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
pyperclip==1.8.0
ruamel.yaml==0.16.10
ruamel.yaml.clib==0.2.0
six==1.15.0
sortedcontainers==2.1.0
tornado==6.0.4
urwid==2.0.1
Werkzeug==1.0.1
wsproto==0.15.0
zstandard==0.13.0
```

But it is hard to say if it needs some C/C++ libraries for this.

For example `pyOpenSSL` will need library `OpenSSL` but I can't find it in [setup.py](https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl/blob/master/setup.py) or [setup.cfg](https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl/blob/master/setup.cfg). There is only information about `openssl-devel` which means it may need `openssl`.

It seems the only way is to install and run it to see error messages :)